# Why am i getting only a single row when i am looping through the arraylist

Tags: arraylist

I have a class called TableRow,which contains the columns from the database that i need to print.I created an ArrayList and added the resultset into this arraylist.Now when am trying to loop through this arraylist,to print all the elements in the arraylist,am not able to do it.It is printing only one row of data instead of the entire table.

Comment: Can you post your array and your markup too?

Comment: ArrayList<TableRow> dataList=new ArrayList<TableRow>();
TableRow trow=new TableRow();

Comment: Integer order_no=rs.getInt("ord_no");
String name=rs.getString("name");
String mobile=rs.getString("mobile");
String add=rs.getString("address");
float rate=rs.getFloat("rate");
float mrp=rs.getFloat("mrp");
String cdate=rs.getString("create_date");
String edate=rs.getString("edited_date");
String status=rs.getString("status");

Comment: trow.setOrd_no(order_no);
trow.setName(name);
trow.setMobile(mobile);
trow.setAddress(add);
trow.setRate(rate);
trow.setMrp(mrp);
trow.setCreate_date(cdate);
trow.setEdited_date(edate);
trow.setStatus(status);

trow.getOrd_no();
trow.getName();
trow.getMobile();
trow.getAddress();
trow.getRate();
trow.getMrp();
trow.getCreate_date();
trow.getEdited_date();
trow.getStatus();
dataList.add(trow);

Comment: i take the result set and put it into the arraylist<tablerows>Please help me through this

Comment: i am doing this to iterate through the array and print the table based on a condition for(TableRow t:dataList){
 if(finaldiff>2.0){
%>
<tr>
<td><%=trow.getOrd_no()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getName()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getMobile()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getAddress()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getRate()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getMrp()%></td> 
<td><%=trow.getCreate_date()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getEdited_date()%></td>
<td><%=trow.getStatus()%></td>
</tr>
 


<%

 }
}

Comment: Can you post what does this code outputs `echo "<pre>"; print_r(dataList);`.

Comment: [TableRow [164,20.0,1000.0, 2013-10-15 10:40:03.0, 2013-10-26 05:20:45.0, checked, arti, katraj,8901], TableRow [164,20.0,1000.0, 2013-10-15 10:40:03.0, 2013-10-26 05:20:45.0, checked, arti, katraj,8901], TableRow [164,20.0,1000.0, 2013-10-15 10:40:03.0, 2013-10-26 05:20:45.0, checked, arti, katraj,8901],

Comment: please add you code for getting result set.

Comment: in the dataList,data is there,the rows are there,but when am trying to iterate and print it as per the condition it doesnt give anything

Comment: i dont why the arraylist is displaying the same data.All the data from the databse should be insterted into the arraylist

Comment: can you add your markup in the question how you are creating the datalist?

Comment: how i define my arraylist if given in the first comment.The tableRow is a class the contains the fields with the getters and setters.

Comment: chck this `if(finaldiff>2.0)` condition. As well as check how many times the loop `for(TableRow t:dataList)` iterates.

Comment: thankyou for you support.The issue got solved.i was making the object outside while loop,thats y i was getting only the last entry in the arraylist.when i made an object inside while loop,the issue was resolved.